# Failed dictionary comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm fixing to create a clone of r (baptized x) but with the keys sorted and the values maintained so I can have a = x. When tried this below the output is quite flabbergasting.

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
r = {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
X = {i: j for i in sorted(r.keys()) for j in r.values()}

print(x)
```

output

```
>>> {'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following dictionary comprehension:

```
print({k: r[k] for k in a.keys()})
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```